# Sound won't come out after unpairing with bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, bluetooth, windows-10-v1909

here's my situation:

My OS is Windows 10 Pro.
my usual audio output is through my TV (because i'm using my TV as monitor with HDMI)
at one time i use my bluetooth headset as audio output and i use it until i turn off my computer.

here's the problem, after i turn on my computer again, there is no sound that came out from my TV even when the audio output is set to my TV. plus, every video player got lagged (youtube video will buffer even though the internet is fine or the video will be slow-mo by itself and the sound won't come out / vlc,windows media player EVERY video player will be lagging or in slow-mo)

when i connect the bluetooth headset to my computer and set the audio output to it, the audio came out and every video player will play just fine.

i have tried to uninstall every audio driver and bluetooth driver in my computer and i still got this problem. anyone can help me solve this problem? before i decided to reset the computer.

thanks!

Comment: Tried unplugging the HDMI cable and plugging it back in? this should reinstall the HDMI audio driver.

Comment: @LPChip i have tried it and the problem still persist.